# Cannot POST to Firebase Function with Alamofire

Tags: swift, firebase, express, alamofire, google-cloud-functions

I have an express app running on a Firebase Function.

I'm trying to POST to a route:

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("POST to <domain>/client/test");
    res.status(200).send({"result" : "POST to <domain>/client/test"});
});
```

and in `app.js` I have:

```
const client = require('./api/client');
app.use('/client', client);
```

In Swift I have the following Alamofire call:

```
Alamofire.request("\(domain)/test", method: .post).responseJSON { response in
    print(response)
}
```

with `let domain = "https://www.<domain>/client"`

If my route is a `GET` then everything works fine, however as a `POST` it never hits `console.log()` and a `404` response is logged in the server logs. I've tried with parameters, and with `encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody`, however nothing seems to work.

I have a global middleware function that intercepts all calls, and I can confirm that it is reaching this - my problem is that I don't know how to tell why it won't reach the next route if it's a `POST`.

Are there some headers I should be setting or something? Lots of other people seem to have similar problems, and all the solutions seem to be minor errors, like incorrect paths etc.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the `response.request`:

```
Optional(https://<domain>/client/test)
```

and the `response.response`:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1c023d380> 
    { URL: https://<domain>/client/test } 
    { status code: 404, 

    headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 150;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 02 Jan 2018 20:18:16 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31556926";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Cookie";
    Via = "1.1 varnish";
    "content-security-policy" = "default-src 'self'";
    "function-execution-id" = 06xe489mx5h7;
    "x-cache" = MISS;
    "x-cache-hits" = 0;
    "x-cloud-trace-context" = "3e45280291033d81bfa5786579121385;o=1";
    "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
    "x-powered-by" = Express;
    "x-served-by" = "cache-wlg7321-WLG";
    "x-timer" = "S1514924296.067148,VS0,VE391";
} })
```

Comment: Have you tried with Postman (or other REST client tools) first? You need to make sure your API works fine before trying to integrate with Swift.

Comment: Yep, I can successfully post to that route with Postman - just not in the Swift client. Which is why I presume it has something to do with the headers - I just have absolutely no idea what headers I might need. I can post from Swift to a normal express app (without setting any headers) - this is specifically when I'm running it as a firebase function.

Comment: I'm also not ruling out a silly mistake on my behalf, but I've been careful to check everything.

Comment: Can you update the question with the response which Alamofire returns?

Comment: Yep but it's just the default output that it returns when it receives an improper response from the server (`responseSerializationFailed`). In this case it's because the server never sends it anything because it never makes it into the route.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `response.request` and `response.response`, which contain the info about the header, the url, the error...